# Appropriate questions/etiquette after receiving offer letter

Tags: job-offer, recruitment, hiring

I had interviewed with a company about a year ago for a similar but different position, and at the time, they told me I was one of 3 final candidates for 1-2 positions. They said that they would like to offer me the position and asked my salary expectations. I gave them a number, and it was about $10k higher than they were looking to pay, so they went with another candidate, and told me that they would keep me in mind, as they would likely be looking to hire again within a couple months. Fast forward a year, and I received an email out of the blue asking me if I was still looking for a position. I interviewed last week, and received the offer letter this morning. I am not surprised by the salary, as they sent me the ZipRecruiter ad that they had posted for the position, and it listed a range, which my offer is for the high end of that range. The offer letter does mention that after a 90 day Onboarding period, I will be offered a full time salaried position. However, it didn't mention anything about benefits such as health insurance, 401(k), or holidays. It is a small company (10-15 employees, from what I can tell), and I was unable to find much info from researching them, no presence on GlassDoor and outside of their website, social media, and Yellow Pages, there isn't anything on Google. As I can't find anything useful from internet research, I am curious to see what the potential pay increase is after 90 days, and what kind of benefits package they have. I asked about the potential pay increase in the interview last week, but they gave a non-answer, so I let the conversation move on, and I didn't remember to ask about benefits.  Is it appropriate to ask these questions after receiving the offer letter?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it appropriate to ask these questions after receiving the offer
>   letter?

The only way you can accurately evaluate an offer is by understanding all details of the offer - including benefits. You should also understand more about the company (such as the size).

Ask for some time to discuss these details before you make you decision. If necessary, write a list for yourself so you don't forget to ask something important again.

Know what you are really getting into before you say yes or no.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I may have understated how much I know about the company. I have a pretty good idea of what I am getting into, and realistically, there's not much that would make me say no to this offer at this point. These are really the only things I don't know. I guess what I should have asked is, is it appropriate to ask these things through email?